# PHP template with function

Tags: php, templates

I got a function that has to display his values to a html page but it won't work.

PHP code:

```
$template = file_get_contents("main.tpl.php");

function updateForm($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM platen WHERE ID =". $id;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        $editForm = "<form action='index.php?update&id=". $row['ID'] ."' method='post'>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='id'><span>ID:</span></label> <input name='id' id='id' type='text' value='". $row['ID'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='album'><span>Album:</span></label> <input name='album' id='album' type='text' value='". $row['Album'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='band'>Band:</label> <input name='band' id='band' type='text' value='". $row['Band'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='stijl'>Stijl:</label> <input name='stijl' id='stijl' type='text' value='". $row['Stijl'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='medium'>Medium:</label> <input name='medium' id='medium' type='text' value='". $row['Medium'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='datum'>Datum:</label> <input name='datum' id='datum' type='text' value='". $row['Datum'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='prijs'>Prijs:</label> <input name='prijs' id='prijs' type='text' value='". $row['Prijs'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<input class='submit' type='submit' value='Update'>";
        $editForm .= "</form>";
    }
$template = str_replace("%%editForm%%",  $editForm, $template);
} 

echo $template;
```

In my HTML file I got %%editForm%% but when I try this it says $template is undefined.
Hope you can help me or know another solution to display the data in the HTML file.

Comment: try this `$template = file_get_contents("main.tpl.php"); echo $template;` and see if you get any output

Comment: I got echo $template; in my php file just forgot it to type:)

Comment: i mean what do you see. do you see anything when you `echo $template;`

Comment: `$template` is a local variable in the functions scope. Pass it in and return it to the outside. Also the loop and the str_replace won't do what you intend (it'll replace all instances of `%%editForm%%` with form fields for just the first row).

Comment: Yes everything that is outside the function in $template gets displayed.

Comment: But if I move $template = str_replace("%%editForm%%",  $editForm, $template); outside the function I get an error saying that $editForm is undefined. But isn't there a better way to do this without the $template?

Answer (score 0):

It says $template is undefinded because it's not visible from functionscope.
You need to pass $template to the function or add `global $template;` inside of your function:

```
 function updateForm($id)
 {
   global $template;
   $query = "SELECT * FROM platen WHERE ID =". $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function updateForm($id,$template)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just pass it to the function.

```
$template = file_get_contents("main.tpl.php");

function updateForm($id, $template)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM platen WHERE ID =". $id;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        $editForm = "<form action='index.php?update&id=". $row['ID'] ."' method='post'>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='id'><span>ID:</span></label> <input name='id' id='id' type='text' value='". $row['ID'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='album'><span>Album:</span></label> <input name='album' id='album' type='text' value='". $row['Album'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='band'>Band:</label> <input name='band' id='band' type='text' value='". $row['Band'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='stijl'>Stijl:</label> <input name='stijl' id='stijl' type='text' value='". $row['Stijl'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='medium'>Medium:</label> <input name='medium' id='medium' type='text' value='". $row['Medium'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='datum'>Datum:</label> <input name='datum' id='datum' type='text' value='". $row['Datum'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<label for='prijs'>Prijs:</label> <input name='prijs' id='prijs' type='text' value='". $row['Prijs'] ."'></br>";
        $editForm .= "<input class='submit' type='submit' value='Update'>";
        $editForm .= "</form>";
    }
$template = str_replace("%%editForm%%",  $editForm, $template);
}
```